# Asp.net updating session values from asynchronous thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, session

In my ASP.Net MVC application i need to initialize a long running function using a thread. After the thread is initialized the response is returned and a page is loaded. From this page, an ajax request is fired every 30 seconds to check the status of the long running function from a value stored in session (this value is updated from within the child thread).
The problem arises because once the response is returned the HttpContext.Current becomes null and even if this HttpContext.Current is passed from the parent to the child thread the session attribute is null. So, i cannot set the session value from the child thread.  Also, as we are implementing a load balanced environment with a non-sticky session I cannot use the application cache.
Can i get the session data in the child thread using the sessionId of the parent call and update it? Or can it be done some other way?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using loadbalancer only proper storage for your data would be a database (or any kind of memcache)

e.g.:
When User requested page:

1. add pending record to database
2. initiate thread to do background calculations (record id is an argument)
3. Store this record id into session

when thread complete:

4. Update record in database

when customer visit back you can easily track if your long running function is done.

You should not touch session itself. In case you find a way to update session (e.g. with mssql session stage) but it happened to update session within next customer request your changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I would create a static dictionary, hash table, etc. (let's say dictionary for the sake of argument) with the key as the session ID. Store that dictionary somewhere that's accessible to both your page and the long-running function (perhaps in a static class?). When your page/application/whatever starts the long-running function, have it add an entry to the dictionary for itself (with the session ID as the key). It can check the value of that dictionary entry every callback. The long-running function would take in the session ID when it's called, and when it's done it could use that to access the entry in the dictionary.

One catch here - that dictionary could get quite large if you don't clear it out when you're done with it. I'd suggest having the page remove the entry from the dictionary once it's checked it and seen that the long-running function has finished. I'd probably also (as an extra safety mechanism) add code to the session end event in your Global.asax file to check if that dictionary has an entry with the ID of the session that's ending and, if so, remove it.